# How to graphically connect nodes by drawing on canvas and tracking the new connection in the events in vis.js?

Tags: vis.js

E.g. I may want to connect "Audi' node with existing "Cars" node to make a connection between the two. This should fire an event so that the underlying data source can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

VIS.js provide some good examples on its page. Check this link and you should find everything you need.

Example: http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/manipulation.html

The important element is the "manipulation" configuration of the network with its callbacks for addNode, editNode, etc.

Dokumentation http://visjs.org/docs/network/manipulation.html